# jquery UI dialog default first button style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, dialog

I want to use jquery dialog with my custom buttons but I don't want first button to be styled like it is clicked...

The same is here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation
If you don't do anything, the button "Delete all items" will be colored in orange. This style will disappear if you click anywhere on the page.

In my app the same thing is always happening to the first button no matter how many buttons are there... So can I make all buttons the same without highlighting the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colouration here is indicating something more. The orange is indicating the current focus. This helps when using keyboard support, meaning if you press enter that button will be activated; as to be expected, tabbing between the two buttons functions as you might expect.

With that in mind, there are two options:

1. Remove focus from the button when the dialogue is generated.
2. Style the button using the `ui-state-focus` to differentiate it from `ui-state-hover` and `ui-state-active`.

I'd say it's unwise to remove the focus since then you obfuscate keyboard support. Instead, go for the less invasive approach by embracing the keyboard support. Style the classes that the jQuery UI maintains to provide a subtle difference in the button appearance so that the behaviour is more apparent.

Comment: Right, the coloration is there for a reason - the user knows what happens if they just press enter. You can change the style but on behalf of the users of your site please don't remove it completely.